# Does you PC have to be on the same wifi to use WOL?

Tags: networking, ip, remote-access, lan, wake-on-lan

Sorry if this is basic stuff, I am not involved in that stuff and don't really understand a lot about it, with that being said:

I want to use WOL to wake up my PC from about 10km away, so I wont be using the same wifi. How would I set it up? Is there an app for it? What addresses from ipconfig do I need to use?

I have already googled but it only yielded results I did not understand or they were outdated af.

I hope you can help and tell me if something was unclear :)